# delphi custom component with default popupmenu item

Tags: delphi, components, popupmenu

I use a custom listview component and I need it to have a popupmenu item "copy data to clipboard". If there is no assigned popup, I create one and add the menuitem, if there is already a menu assigned, add the item to the current popup. Tried to put the code in the constructor, but then I realized, that popupmenu is still not created or associated to my listview. So any idea when to create my default item?

```
constructor TMyListView.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  FpopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
begin
  inherited;
  .....
  FPopUpMenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(self);
  FPopUpMenuItem.Caption := 'Copy data to clipboard';
  FPopUpMenuItem.OnClick := PopupMenuItemClick;
  if assigned(PopupMenu) then begin
    popupMenu.Items.Add(FPopUpMenuItem);
  end
  else begin
    FpopupMenu := TPopupMenu.Create(self);
    FpopupMenu.Items.Add(FPopUpMenuItem);
    PopupMenu := FpopupMenu;
  end;
...
end;
```

Comment: What are you doing, when the PopupMenu already contains the "Copy data to clipboard"-`TMenuItem`?

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Consider a [mcve].  What version of Delphi?

Comment: What if the developer assigns a popup at runtime? What you need to do is to expose an accessible method and leave the rest to component user.

Comment: I am the developer. Users want to be able to copy/paste selected data from any listview in the existing software with over 100 occurrences. So I was thinking to add a "fixed" item to the menus.. Seems there is no way to do that as I don't get notified if a popup is assigned to my listview. Can't override TControl.SetPopupMenu too, it is private and non-virtual..

Comment: Work at runtime, handle wm_contextmenu, see if a popup is attached, if it is attached see if "copy data..." is already appended, append it otherwise. Create a popup if none is attached.

Comment: Rather than handle `WM_CONTEXTMENU` directly, override the virtual `TControl.DoContextPopup()` method, ore even the `TControl.GetPopupMenu()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the virtual [`TControl.DoContextPopup()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.DoContextPopup) method, eg:

```
type
  TMyListView = class(TListView)
  protected
    ...
    procedure DoContextPopup(MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean); override;
    ...
  end;

procedure TMyListView.DoContextPopup(MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  LPopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
  LItem: TMenuItem;

  function IsSameEvent(const E1, E2: TNotifyEvent): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := (TMethod(E1).Code = TMethod(E2).Code) and
              (TMethod(E1).Data = TMethod(E2).Data);
  end;

begin
  inherited DoContextPopup(MousePos, Handled);
  if Handled then Exit;

  LPopupMenu := PopupMenu;
  if not Assigned(LPopupMenu) then
  begin
    LPopupMenu := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
    PopupMenu := LPopupMenu;
  end;

  for I := 0 to LPopupMenu.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
    LItem := LPopupMenu.Items[I];
    if IsSameEvent(LItem.OnClick, PopupMenuItemClick) then
      Exit;
  end;

  LItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  LItem.Caption := 'Copy data to clipboard';
  LItem.OnClick := PopupMenuItemClick;
  LPopupMenu.Items.Add(LItem);
end;
```

Comment: Works perfect and applies to any control. Thank you very much, Remy!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer indeed works perfectly - unless you add keyboard shortcuts to your menu item. If you do, these won't work before the popup menu has been accessed in some other way, because the items will not have been created.
If you need shortcuts, it may therefore be preferable to move the code from `DoContextPopup` to `Loaded`. Most simply,

```
procedure Loaded; override;
...
procedure Loaded; 
var 
  MI: TMenuItem;
  ItemCovered: boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  inherited;
  if not Assigned(PopupMenu) then 
    PopupMenu:=TPopupMenu.Create(self);
  ItemCovered:=false;
  for i := 0 to PopupMenu.Items.Count-1 do
    if IsSameEvent(PopupMenu.Items[I].OnClick, CopyDataToClipboardClick) then begin 
      ItemCovered:=true;
      break;
    end;
  if not ItemCovered then begin
    MI:=TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu);
    MI.Caption:='Copy data to clipboard';
    MI.OnClick:=CopyDataToClipboardClick;
    MI.ShortCut:=ShortCut(Ord('C'),[ssShift,ssCtrl]);
    PopupMenu.Items.Add(MI);
  end;
end;
```

This won't check for popup menus added on runtime, but probably serve most cases better.